# How to get a bit of text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following scenario where I need to get text from a specific id area, for instance, in this case I'd like to get the name of the person. I already know the id i.e. booking_11 as I've got this from the onClick:

```
<li id="booking_11">Name of person <span style="float: right;"><a href="#" id="11" class="dialog">View</a> | <a class="remove" id="rmCandidate_11" href="#">Remove</a></span></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get *only* that `"Name of person"` text node you can do this (without changing your markup):

```
var name = $("#booking_11").contents().filter(function() { 
                                           return this.nodeType == 3; 
                                       }).text();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/dTde9/) (broken up above to fit SO cleanly, it can be a one-liner).

Comment: Excellant, worked like a charm. I don't have a clue what it does though? How does it get the text?

Comment: @user275074 - It takes the contents, all child nodes including the text one, and looks for only the text nodes (excluding the span), and takes the text of those...which is the name.

Answer (score 1):

Make a div/span like this:

```
<span class="test">Name of person</span> View | Remove
```

And then:

```
jQuery('#booking_11 > .test').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('booking_11').text();
```

Comment: Will this not return everything in my li? All other elements and text? I just want the first bit before the span but after the li id.

Comment: Well as you've edited the question to now include the html... Kevin's answer looks good