# Get span contents but ignore H2. JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have a `span` that contains text that I would like to use. But within this `span` there is a `h2` that I want to ignore. (This isnt my mark up and I cant change this so moving the `h2` outside of the `span` is not an option)

Here is the mark up:

```
<span>
<h2>Joe Bloggs</h2>
Executive Director
</span>
```

Here is my current code which is getting the contents of the `span` including the `h2`

```
currentLi = $('ul#example2 li.frame3');

position = $(currentLi).find('span').text();
```

So my hopeful outcome will be the variable `position` containing the text "Executive Director"

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154171/how-to-get-a-bit-of-text-using-jquery

Comment: IMHO it's not a strict duplicate of any of these - this one is asking for everything except specifically an H2 child node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) with [`.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents). Inside the `filter` function you can evaluate the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) property, ensuring that it is `3` (text nodes only):

```
var onlySpan = $("span").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text().trim();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wp4FR/

Comment: Just like that. Good answer. +1

Comment: note that this will also remove _any_ other HTML child nodes of the `<span>`, not just an `<h2>`.

Comment: it works very well thankyou. But could you possibly explain to me what the nodetype === 3 is, Thats the only part I dont understand. Thanks.

Comment: `nodeType === 3` is checking for *only* text nodes that are children of the `span`. That gets rid of all HTML child nodes (as @Alnitak stated above)

Answer (score 3):

Clone the span, remove the `<h2>`, and get the remaining text.

```
var clone = $(document).find('span').clone();
$(clone).find('h2').remove();

var position = $(clone).text().trim();
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ukFWq/

Answer (score 0):

this is something which i will never suggest you, but as per your requirement following code can work.

```
    var index = position.indexOf('</h2>');
    position = position.substring(index+5, position.length)
    alert(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use the [textchildren](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/textchildren/#download) plugin

You can find a demo in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Qm68/)

All you have to do is to use the plugin like this

```
$('span').textChildren()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the not filter.

```
currentLi = $('ul#example2 li.frame3');

position = $(currentLi).find('span:not(h2).text()').text();
```

you might be able to do it with a not method as well

```
span.not(h2)
```